# Firebase Database strange ordering

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this "chat-system" that I made with Firebase Database.

To retrieve the messages in the Room I do a `Query` with an `orderByChild(timestamp)` then reverse the order so I can get the "newest" Last (Because I start reading from the Bottom).

```
    messageList = new ArrayList<>();
    final Query query = chatRef_1.orderByChild("
            query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    messageList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class));
                    updateRecyclerView();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    messageList.remove(dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class));
                    updateRecyclerView();

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

But then I get this result

[image]

- This only happens with `ChildEventListener`
- The TimeStamp is done by the server
- Does anyone have an Idea of what this might be?

## UPDATE


Here's the database Structure

[image]

- Box »» Object (Message)
- Green »» MessageID
- Blue »» RoomID

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: You seem to have made a little mistake when posting your code here. The orderByChild isn't complete.

Comment: you given image to show result or currently it show like that result. i don't understand your problem